# Self Signed SSL Cert - Browser Warning

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate

I generated a new self-signed cert for one of our intranet sites. The old cert expired today. I pushed the new cert out via GPO and deleted the old one. I can see on the client that the new cert has been installed, but I still get a warning when users visit the site. This wasn't an issue until today (when the new cert went out). Here are some details:

The cert is installed on the machine ("clinton"):

[image]

---

The cert info:

[image]

---

The browser warning:

[image]

---

I double checked in chrome settings and I can see the certificate there as well. Any ideas?

Comment: If you click the HTTPS bit in Chrome it should tell you why...

Comment: I went to check it today to get that info, and its showing green. I guess the current date needs to be later than the start date of the cert (instead of the same day)?

Comment: Chrome caches SSL certs. Sometimes I have to open an incognito window to see the proper green lock.